# Android разработка, что нужно знать для клиент-серверной части?

Tags: android, сервер

Есть небольшой опыт в java и php, но, к сожалению, никогда не сталкивался с get/post запросами, писал лишь серверы и небольшие парсеры с выводом заголовка, текста и всё. Хотелось бы обучиться этому, пробовал поискать в гугле, мне выдало лишь банальные примеры без объяснения. На каких сайтах искать подобные темы?

Comment: Опыт php и не сталкивались с get/post запросами. Мистика прям.

Comment: просто человек делал странички, поэтому и не сталкивался.

Для того, чтобы написать серверную часть, можно использовать любую технологию, которая умеет принимать/передавать по tcp (к примеру, тот же http). Это может быть и php, и java+tomcat, и даже ассемблер.

Comment: Я думаю методом REST, это же вроде тот же get/post?

Comment: REST - это не метод. Это соглашение. А get/post - это часть http, который REST активно использует.